# how to set this Jquery code into body onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys im new to jquery/ javascript. i found some code in w3schools and i want to use it in my website. but i want the animation to trigger ever time i load the page. please help me how to do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Demonstrate fadeToggle() with different speed parameters.</p>
    <button>Click to fade in/out boxes</button>
    <br><br>

    <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i want to do something like this

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean you want to trigger the `fadeToggle` onload?

Comment: yes i want the fadetoggle() to start/trigger everytime i load/refresh the page

Comment: cause base on w3schools example it will only animate when i click the button.

Comment: i see. i already answered. :)

Comment: `The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the <body onload=""> attribute.` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: `window.onload()` is the correct option for you!

Comment: See this link http://jsfiddle.net/3oj95qgs/

Comment: `.ready()` does the same what you want to do with `onload`. See the above example of @pawanLakhara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#div1").fadeToggle();
    $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>   Instead of <h1>Hello World!</h1>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#div1").fadeToggle();
     $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
     $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are approaching for executing the function after Page loaded, then Put below `JavaScript` at end of your `HTML` design:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = myFunction();
</script>
```

And define the function at start of the Page as you've done already!
So, final Code becomes like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Demonstrate fadeToggle() with different speed parameters.</p>
    <button>Click to fade in/out boxes</button>
    <br><br>

    <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = myfunction();
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Let me know by accepting it, if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to use event listener.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load',myfunction,false);
</script>
```